# Can somebody explain the reasoning behind decimal to binary conversion?

Tags: binary, digital-design

I know the concept of division by 2 & then taking the remainder but I want to know how this method actually works. I want a mathematical derivation for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mathematical derivation you are asking for is based on the `remainder theorem`, which states that:
`Dividend = Divisor*Quotient + Remainder`

Now consider a decimal number X. We can express X in binary form as follows:
`X= a*2^0  + b*2^1 + c*2^2 + d*2^3 .........................`

Our aim is to find the values of coefficients `a,b,c,d...` to express the number in binary form.

Now if you `divide X by 2`, you will get 'a' as the remainder & the corresponding quotient would be `(b*2^0 + c*2^1 + d*2^2 ........)`

Now if we divide the above quotient again by 2 we will get 'b' as the remainder & this cycle will go on until we get all coefficients which will give us the final binary form.